# How to Let JavaScript Apps Loaded from Any Domain Access All Public Assets When CORS Is Enabled

Tags: scala, playframework, cors

In my **Play** application I've implemented a filter that enables **CORS** by defaul... but since the backend also sends emails to users (e.g. password reset, user verification after registration, etc.) and these HTML emails need to access some public assets (i.e. icons, logo, etc), I'm wondering how to let anyone access all assets in `/public`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't implemented any authentication logic yet everything should be publicly accessible. It is up to an e-mail client if it allows external http resources in mail content and CORS has nothing to do with it.